# How to return a key if an element exists in List from Hash<String,List<Object>>?

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting

I need to get the key if the list in the key contains a specific value in it.

The way only I can think of is iterating the HashMap and also for loop for the List of each key's value and then check if the List contains the value and return the key. Something like this:

```
Map<String, List<MyItem>> map = new HashMap<>();
List<MyItem> list = new List<>();
list.add(new MyItem("Kim", 25);
list.add(new MyItem("Lee", 28);
map.put("Samsung", list);

String searchKeyWord = "Kim";
String myKey = getKeyByValue(map, searchKeyWord);

System.out.println("Found Key: " + myKey);
```

I don't know what's the best way is.

1.

```
public String getKeyByValue(Map<String, List<MyItem> map, String searchKeyWord) {
    boolean flag = false;
    String myKey = null;

    for (Entry<String, List<MyItem>> e : map.entrySet()) {
        String currentKey = e.getKey();
        List<MyItem> myItemList = e.getValue();
        Collections.sort(myItemList, this);
        for (int i = 0 ; i < myItemList.size() ; i++) {
            if (myItemList.get(i).name.equals(searchKeyWord)) {
                myKey = currentKey;
                flag = true;
            }
            if (flag) {
                break;
            }
        }
        if (flag) {
            break;
        }
    }
    return (flag ? myKey : null);
}
```

2.

```
public String getKeyByValue(Map map, String searchKeyWord){
    boolean flag = false;
    String myKey = null;

    for(Entry<String, List<MyItem>> e: map.entrySet()){
        String currentKey = e.getKey();
        List<MyItem> myItemList = e.getValue();
        Collections.sort(myItemList, this);
        if(binarySearch(myItemList, searchKeyWord)){
            myKey = currentKey;
            flag = true;
        }
    }

    if(flag) return myKey;
    else null;
}
```

3. Using HashMap instead of List.
4. Using Multi-value(Guava)

Or other methods...

Should I change the data structure? What's the best search algorithm for this?

Comment: `map.entrySet().stream().filter(entry -> entry.getValue().stream().anyMatch(item -> item.name.equals(searchKeyWord))).map(Entry::getKey).findAny().orElse(null)`

Comment: Good lord...one-liner all-star solutions are tarnishing the beauty....

Comment: `for (Entry<String, List<MyItem>> entry : map.entrySet()) for (MyItem item : entry.getValue()) if (item.name.equals(searchKeyWord)) return true; return false;`

Comment: Sorting is a waste of time.

Comment: I have to ask @shmosel, if it's worthy, why not just answer it so you can provide some context and detail?

Comment: ..you seem to misunderstand (Hash)`Map`: it makes sense, when you want to (really quickly) access "objects" by *one* key ...and the count of objects is `<= pow(2, 31) - 1`

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils Maybe it's not worthy. Or maybe I'm lazy.

Comment: ..so make (additionally to) your data structure a: `HashMap<String, MyItem> name2Item;`, and `name2Item.put(item.name(), item)` ..for every item.

Comment: Fair enough @shmosel, but not lazy enough maybe? Answers in comments, as I've seen and believe, are less than great or sufficient. If they like what you comment, then a stream of clarifying comments ensue. Later, they may finally extract a full answer from that stream of back-and-forth and it will be buried, if not lost, in the comments never to be helpful again.

Comment: ..if you want additionally (super quick) access "Samsung" from "Kim", I would (additionally!) maintain `HashMap<MyItem, String> items2Company`, too.

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils I understand, but I think it's better than nothing.

Comment: @xerx593 I need the key to find its value, but also vice-versa .

Comment: @shmosel double for-loop doesn't seem efficient though..

Comment: Compared to what?

Comment: @shmosel I don't know the first solution's time complexity, but the second one doesn't seem efficient when the data is very large compared to other search algorithms. For example, once you sort with Quick Sort and Binary Search, It's O(N log N) + O(log M), And it's O(N log NM).

Comment: But it's not sorted, or you wouldn't be sorting it.

Comment: If the list cannot or should not contain duplicates, then you might want to try `HashSet` instead of a `List`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Explanation in comments:

```
private static String getKeyByValue(Map<String, List<MyItem>> map, String searchKeyWord) {
    return map.entrySet().stream()      //all entries in the map
            .filter(e -> e.getValue().stream()
                    .anyMatch(i -> i.getName().equals(searchKeyWord))) //take only the ones which have searchKeyword in their list
            .findAny()                  //take just one such entry
            .map(Map.Entry::getKey)     //change Entry to String (the key)
            .orElse(null);              //if there is no such entry, return null
}
```

As @MCEmperor suggested, you can change `String` to `Optional<String>` return type and get rid of `.orElse(null);`.

---

Or if you have a lot of elements, you can avoid scanning the whole lists by using a data structure like `Map<String, Map<String, MyItem>>` like this:

```
Map<String, Map<String, MyItem>> m = new HashMap<>();

Map<String, MyItem> items = Map.of(
        "Kim", new MyItem("Kim", 25),
        "Lee", new MyItem("Lee", 28)
);

m.put("Samsung", items);

String result = m.entrySet().stream()
        .filter(e -> e.getValue().containsKey(searchKeyWord))
        .findAny()
        .map(Map.Entry::getKey)
        .orElse(null);
```

Comment: Note that I would instead return an empty `Optional` instead of `null`, but that's just a matter of personal taste, I guess...

Comment: @MCEmperor completely agree. Updated.

Comment: Thanks, But may I know it's time complexity?

Comment: @ChanjungKim The first approach scans each element of Map until it finds a match, so it is O(n), and then it scans all the elements of list, which is O(m), so the total becomes `O(mn)`. The second approach does the two things in O(n) and O(1), so it is `O(n)`. I'm not very good with O notation, so I might be wrong.